# Combine two attributeContains selectors

Tags: jquery

I want to search for id's that contain either `A1` or `D2`.

I can search for elements that matches `div[id*="A1"]` **OR** `div[id*="D2"]`, but I want to do this within the same jquery call.

This isn't correct syntax but you'll understand what I want, something like:

```
$('div[id*="A1"] || div[id*="D2"]').html("Here it is");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
$('div').filter('[id*="A1"], [id*="D2"]').html("Here it is");
```

or a multiple selector

```
$('div[id*="A1"], div[id*="D2"]').html("Here it is").html("Here it is");
```

<sub>I personally like the first method</sub>

Comment: Hm, why didn't I think of that. Thank you!